# Error Spring when instantiating bean

Tags: java, spring

I have this error when building and I don't know what is the problem. Do you have any ideas? Can you please explain it to me?

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.atas.service.DynamicListService com.atlasaas.listeners.SelectItemsEventListener.dynamicListService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dynamicLists': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.atlasaas.service.GenericService com.atlasaas.service.impl.DynamicListServiceImpl.genericService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericServiceImpl': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://myhost.ataas.com:9080/atlas-esb-servicesWeb/sca/IGeneric?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Got vhost5295.atlasaas.com while opening stream from http://myhost.ataas.com:9080/atlas-esb-servicesWeb/sca/IGeneric?wsdl.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://myhost.ataas.com:9080/atlas-esb-servicesWeb/sca/IGeneric?wsdl

Comment: We'd need the code you build to get this.

Failed to access the WSDL at: http://myhost.ataas.com:9080/atlas-esb-servicesWeb/sca/IGeneric?wsdl

So this is probably a duplicate of
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407994/jax-ws-client-cannot-authenticate